# Finding points in a voxel

Tags: python, numpy, spyder, voxel

I've generated a NumPy array for 3 axes (x,y,z). And I have the step size and length of the voxel cube. So my question is how can I find the generated points in that voxel.

[You can see clearly with 3d implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PSai.png)

[Voxel dictionary should look like this and points are shown on the left table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHlBS.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution if anyone wondering

```
def findPointsInAVoxel(pc,lenght,ss):
    voxels={}
    for i in range (0,lenght,ss):
        for j in range (0,lenght,ss):
            for k in range (0,lenght,ss):
                voxels[(i,j,k)]=pc[((pc[:,0]>=i) & (pc[:,0]<=i+ss-1)) & \
                   ((pc[:,1]>=j) & (pc[:,1]<=j+ss-1)) & \
                   ((pc[:,2]>=k) & (pc[:,2]<=k+ss-1))]
    return voxels
```